# Excel VBA range selection based on date range

Tags: excel, date, vba

I´m in early beginning of VBA learning . Need simple code for selecting a range of cell to sum them.

The thing is I manage to found many examples but none of them seems to work. So task is to select range of cells from B:xx to Q:xx if A:xx cell contains date between dd1.mm1.yy1 and dd2.mm2.yy2. That needs to be done in 9 sheets in same workbook

pic of example

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Take time and explain little more what you want to do and what you have done till now.

Comment: What do you mean by "select"?  This is an ambiguous term. It would be helpful if you [edit] your question to explain, what you have, what you're trying to do, and give an example of desired outcome.  Also one thing that will need to change is your dates are going to have to be changed into a proper date format (for your region).

Comment: To determine the correct way to enter dates, try this on a blank cell: Insert current date by holding `CTRL` and hitting `;` (semicolon) and press `ENTER`. Then push `↑` (up-arrow) to go back to the same cell, and format it for your region by holding `CTRL` + `SHIFT` and then push `3`.